# Difference between different serializer

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am working on an API, I see that we can call the Serializer in different ways, I have a question in the below syntax if both are same or different? If they are different, how are they different. I am specifically looking at:
System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer and JavaScriptSerializer()

Comment: Are those not the same thing? If not, what namespace is the second one in?

Comment: Those are the same thing.  Do you know what a namespace is?

Comment: I cannot see any name space. The declaration: Dim serializer As New JavaScriptSerializer()

Comment: @ksk that is VB.Net code.  Why is the question tagged C#?  Do you know how namespaces are imported?

Comment: in a file that says `New JavaScriptSerializer()` it will say `Import System.Web.Script.Serialization` at the top, which allows you not to specify the namespace everywhere else

Comment: In the API code that I am looking at has both are used one after the other, thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are the same class.  The name of the class is `JavaScriptSerializer`, and it is in the `System.Web.Script.Serialization` namespace.

Near the top of your file you should see

```
Import System.Web.Script.Serialization
```

This imports that namespace, allowing you to omit it when referring to classes in that namespace.  With the namespace imported, the following lines are equivalent:

```
New JavaScriptSerializer()
New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer()
```

Comment: *technically* they're not 100% "equivalent" because the second one will disambiguate if there happens to be a second conflicting `JavaScriptSerializer`.

Comment: True, but I don't want to make things too confusing for the OP.